# Pandas DataFrame from dict/column generator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a dict, where keys are column labels and values are Series, I can easily build a DataFrame as such:

```
dat = {'col_1': pd.Series([3, 2, 1, 0], index=range(10,50,10)),
       'col_2': pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7], index=range(10,50,10))}

pd.DataFrame(dat)
```

```
    col_1  col_2
10      3      4
20      2      5
30      1      6
40      0      7
```

However I have a *generator* that gives (key, value) tuples:

```
gen = ((col, srs) for col, srs in dat.items())  # generator object
```

Now I can trivially use the generator to create a dict and make the same Dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(gen))
```

However this evaluates all the generator Series first, and then sends them into Pandas, and so uses twice the memory (I presume). I'd like Pandas to iterate over the generator itself as it builds the DataFrame if possible.

I can pass the generator into the DataFrame constructor, but get an odd result:

```
gen = ((col, srs) for col, srs in dat.items())  # generator object
pd.DataFrame(gen)
```

```
       0                                             1
0  col_1  10    3
20    2
30    1
40    0
dtype: int64
1  col_2  10    4
20    5
30    6
40    7
dtype: int64
```

And I get the same result using `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(gen)` or `pd.DataFrame.from_records(gen)`.

So my questions are: Can I produce my original DataFrame by passing the generator `gen` to Pandas? And by doing so would I reduce my memory usage (assuming a large data set, not the trivial toy example shown here).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can build your dataframe from the generator this way without the need for a conversion to a dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

for x in gen:
    df[x[0]] = x[1]
```

[image]

For the allocated memory for both methods, I tried to compare both on different notebooks or on the same notebook but after restarting and clearing the outputs each time to get true results.

**First method:** converting a generator to dictionary and then dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import psutil
import os


dat = {'col_1': pd.Series([3, 2, 1, 0], index=range(10,50,10)),
       'col_2': pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7], index=range(10,50,10)),
      'col_3': pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7], index=range(10,50,10)),
      'col_4': pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7], index=range(10,50,10)),
      'col_5': pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7], index=range(10,50,10)),
      'col_6': pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7], index=range(10,50,10)),
      'col_7': pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7], index=range(10,50,10)),
      'col_8': pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7], index=range(10,50,10)),
      'col_9': pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7], index=range(10,50,10)),
      'col_10': pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7], index=range(10,50,10))}


gen = ((col, srs) for col, srs in dat.items())  

df =  pd.DataFrame(dict(gen))

print("memory usage is {} MB".format(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / (1024 * 1024)))

#output

Memory usage is 78.55859375 MB
```

**Second method:** creating a dataframe by only iterating through the generator:

```
import pandas as pd
import psutil
import os


dat = {'col_1': pd.Series([3, 2, 1, 0], index=range(10,50,10)),
       'col_2': pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7], index=range(10,50,10)),
      'col_3': pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7], index=range(10,50,10)),
      'col_4': pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7], index=range(10,50,10)),
      'col_5': pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7], index=range(10,50,10)),
      'col_6': pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7], index=range(10,50,10)),
      'col_7': pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7], index=range(10,50,10)),
      'col_8': pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7], index=range(10,50,10)),
      'col_9': pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7], index=range(10,50,10)),
      'col_10': pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7], index=range(10,50,10))}


gen = ((col, srs) for col, srs in dat.items())

df = pd.DataFrame()

for x in gen:
    df[x[0]] = x[1]
    
print("Memory usage is {} MB".format(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / (1024 * 1024)))

#output
Memory usage is 78.69921875 MB
```

**Conclusion**, there is very small difference in terms of memory, but converting a generator to a dictionary more efficient in terms of time.

Comment: dat.items() is the generator object as he indicated in his question.

Comment: Yes, it is a dictionary. Thanks

Comment: Thanks - mine is a toy example, in actuality I do have a `gen` generator, but I don't have the underlying `dat` data. However I could adapt your answer to use the `gen` as @d.b suggests...

Comment: I edited the answer to adapt it with generator with allocated memory for both.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert the generator to a dict and then create a dataframe from it:

```
# Create generator
dat = {'col_1': pd.Series([3, 2, 11, 0], index=range(10,50,10)),
       'col_2': pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7], index=range(10,50,10))}

gen = ((col, srs) for col, srs in dat.items())


# Create df
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(gen))
```

Output:

```
col_1   col_2
10  3   4
20  2   5
30  11  6
40  0   7
```

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned in my question I was looking to the generator directly rather than first convert it to a dict.